# Is Čech cohomology always a contravariant functor?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to wrap my head around this question. Any comments are welcome, but I would prefer to focus on the (non)existence of certain good open covers, since this is really the sticking point for me. Here is the set-up:

Suppose that we have a continuous map $\varphi: X \rightarrow Y$, and good open covers $\mathcal{U} = \{ U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ and $\mathcal{V} = \{ V_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha\in A}$, respectively. For simplicity I will assume that both $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ have the same cardinality. Also, I will take $X$ and $Y$ to be smooth manifolds (but I suppose this doesn't matter much), and $G$ abelian.

In order to construct a homomorphism from $\check{H}^*(Y, G)$ to $\check{H}^*(X, G)$, it makes sense to create a chain map which we can eventually descend to cohomology. Fixing some $k$, I would like to describe an explicit map $g: \check{C}^k(Y,G) \rightarrow \check{C}^k(X,G)$. Using the information available to us, the obvious map is to send each function $f_{\alpha_0 ,..., \alpha_k}: V_{\alpha_0, ..., \alpha_k} \rightarrow G$ to a function in $\tilde{f}_{\alpha_0 ,..., \alpha_k}: U_{\alpha_0, ..., \alpha_k} \rightarrow G$ via the assignment $$f_{\alpha_0 ,..., \alpha_k} \mapsto \tilde{f}_{\alpha_0 ,..., \alpha_k} = f_{\alpha_0 ,..., \alpha_k} \circ \varphi.$$

However, this obvious guess assumes that there is some sort of "compatibility" between the open covers on $X$ and $Y$. Specifically, in order for the map $f_{\alpha_0 ,..., \alpha_k} \circ \varphi$ to actually be a $k$-cochain on $X$, it needs to have domain equal to the intersection $U_{\alpha_0, ..., \alpha_k}$. Therefore, at the very least, we need to assume that $\varphi(U_{\alpha_0, ..., \alpha_k})$ is contained within $V_{\alpha_0, ..., \alpha_k}$, for all $\alpha$.

If this is always possible, then I suppose we can proceed with a standard argument by descending into cohomology.

**My Question**: is it really always the case that we can reorganise/refine good open covers on arbitrary topological spaces so that this compatibility condition $\varphi(U_{\alpha_0, ..., \alpha_k})\subseteq V_{\alpha_0, ..., \alpha_k}$ always holds? Or is there a different argument that bypasses this issue, perhaps by invoking some limiting procedure?

Comment: This is why Cech cohomology is the *limit* of the cohomologies corresponding to covers: so that you can indeed refine coverings. In your context, you need to show that the cohomology corresponding to two good coverings are isomorphic (by comparing them to a good covering that refined them both)

Comment: If you want Cech cohomology with respect to fixed open covers (even if they're good) to be functorial, you need your map to be compatible with those coverings (as you have observed). This problem does not arise in the true Cech cohomology, which is a limit. Then, for each open cover of $Y$, you get an open cover of $X$ by pullback, an induced map between the cohomology groups corresponding to those covers by your construction, and then the actual induced map arises from these in the limit.

Comment: What is a  good open cover? You should give a definition and a reference to a textbook or a paper.

Comment: Mariano and Thorgott thanks for the help, I think I get it now. We can use the "obvious map" I described in my question to relate $\check{H}^*(Y, \mathcal{V}, G)$ to the group $\check{H}^*(X, \varphi^{-1}(\mathcal{V}), G)$. My compatibility condition is then trivially met, since $\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(V_{\alpha}))$ is always contained in $V_\alpha$. Since the honest Cech cohomology on $X$ is a direct limit, the group $\check{H}^*(X, \varphi^{-1}(\mathcal{V}), G)$ will naturally map into $H^*(X,G)$.  Then we just compose these two maps. Is this right?

Comment: @PaulFrost A good open cover of a topological space is one that consists of simply connected subsets $U_\alpha$ whose multiple intersections $U_{\alpha_0 ... \alpha_k}$ are also simply connected. I didn't include a definition or reference, since anybody who knows what Cech cohomology is should also know what good open covers are.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you for your helpful instructions.

Comment: @ArchimedeezNuts Aren't good cover such which consist of contractible subsets whose multiple intersections are also contractible? And I think they only play a role for differentiable manifolds since arbitrary spaces in general do not have any good open covers. This is why the definition of Cech cohomology groups for general spaces is based on arbitrary open covers and a direct limit construction. It seems to me that your interpretation of Cech cohomology differs from this traditional approach (as presented in the classic  "Foundations Of Algebraic Topology" by Eilenberg and Steenrod).